# Name of rectangle with sides parallel/perpendicular to axes

Tags: geometry, terminology

In a two-dimensional coordinate system, what do you call a rectangle where the sides are parallel/perpendicular to axes?

Answer (score 2):

It's called an *axis-aligned* rectangle. From what I know this term comes up most often in "axis-aligned bounding box", which is much simpler to compute than a general bounding box.

Comment: Do you know if it also can be called 'orthogonal rectangle'?

Comment: @matthiash All rectangles are "orthogonal", in a way...